# Jquery loop through and get the form field values

Tags: jquery

I have a form like below:

```js
$('.form').submit(function(e) {
    
      e.preventDefault();
      $(this).find('.choices li').each(function() {
         var $thisChoice = $(this);
        var choiceLabel = $thisChoice.find('.choice-label').val();
           if( $thisChoice.find('textarea.sub_textarea'))
           {
                $thisChoice.find('textarea.sub_textarea').each(function() { 
                    var subChoiceNotes=$(this).val();
                    //var subNotesReqChoice=$(this).next('input.requiredNotes[type=checkbox]').val();
                    var subNotesReqChoice=$(this).next('input.requiredNotes[type=checkbox]:checked').val();
                    alert('NoteLabel:'+subChoiceNotes+'&reqNote:'+subNotesReqChoice);
                });
          }
         
    });
  
});
```

```css
<form class="form">
  <div class="choices">
    <ul> 
      <li class="ui-sortable-handle">Add Choice: <input type="text" value="Choice1" class="choice-label">
        <div  class="parentbox">
          <textarea  name="choice_notes" class="sub_textarea" >note1</textarea>
          <input type="checkbox" class="requiredNotes" value="1"  checked>Required?
          <br/>
          <textarea style="display:inline-block; vertical-align:middle;" name="choice_notes" class="sub_textarea" >note2</textarea>
          <input type="checkbox" class="requiredNotes" value="0">Required?
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="ui-sortable-handle" style="">Add Choice: <input type="text" value="Choice2" class="choice-label">
        <div  class="parentbox">
          <textarea name="choice_notes" class="sub_textarea" >note3</textarea>
          <input type="checkbox" class="requiredNotes" value="1" checked>Required?
          <br/>
          <textarea name="choice_notes" class="sub_textarea" >note4</textarea>
          <input type="checkbox" class="requiredNotes" value="0">Required?
          <br/>
            <textarea  name="choice_notes" class="sub_textarea" >note5</textarea>
          <input type="checkbox" class="requiredNotes" value="1" checked>Required?
          <br/>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
     <input type='submit' class='update' value='submit' />
  </div>
</form>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="form">
  <div class="choices">
    <ul> 
      <li class="ui-sortable-handle">Add Choice: <input type="text" value="Choice1" class="choice-label">
        <div  class="parentbox">
          <textarea  name="choice_notes" class="sub_textarea" >note1</textarea>
          <label><input type="checkbox" class="requiredNotes" value="1"  checked>Required?</label>
          <br/>
          <textarea style="display:inline-block; vertical-align:middle;" name="choice_notes" class="sub_textarea" >note2</textarea>
          <label><input type="checkbox" class="requiredNotes" value="0">Required?</label>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="ui-sortable-handle" style="">Add Choice: <input type="text" value="Choice2" class="choice-label">
        <div  class="parentbox">
          <textarea name="choice_notes" class="sub_textarea" >note3</textarea>
         <label> <input type="checkbox" class="requiredNotes" value="1" checked>Required?</label>
          <br/>
          <textarea name="choice_notes" class="sub_textarea" >note4</textarea>
          <label> <input type="checkbox" class="requiredNotes" value="0">Required?</label>
          <br/>
            <textarea  name="choice_notes" class="sub_textarea" >note5</textarea>
          <label><input type="checkbox" class="requiredNotes" value="1" checked>Required?</label>
          <br/>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
     <input type='submit' class='update' value='submit' />
  </div>
</form>
```

When the form submits, I want to loop through all the choices in the `li` tag and store the values in a variable.

I am getting the text area values when loop through the `li` tag. I want to get the value of checkbox with the  text area values. The checkbox value should be the value of checkbox near the text area.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Add name attributes to your checkboxes and then use `var subNotesReqChoice=$(this).next('input.requiredNotes[type=checkbox]').val();` to get the checkboxes regardless of them been selected or not.

```js
$('.form').submit(function(e) {
    
      e.preventDefault();
      $(this).find('.choices li').each(function() {
         var $thisChoice = $(this);
        var choiceLabel = $thisChoice.find('.choice-label').val();
            alert('FOR CHOICE:'+choiceLabel);
           if( $thisChoice.find('textarea.sub_textarea'))
           {
                $thisChoice.find('textarea.sub_textarea').each(function() { 
                    var subChoiceNotes=$(this).val();
                    var subNotesReqChoice=$(this).next('input.requiredNotes[type=checkbox]').val();
                    alert('NoteLabel:'+subChoiceNotes+'&reqNote:'+subNotesReqChoice);
                });
          }
         
    });
  
});
```

```css
<form class="form">
  <div class="choices">
    <ul> 
      <li class="ui-sortable-handle">Add Choice: <input type="text" value="Choice1" class="choice-label">
        <div  class="parentbox">
          <textarea  name="choice_notes" class="sub_textarea" >note1</textarea>
          <input type="checkbox" name="requiredNotes" class="requiredNotes" value="1"  checked>Required?
          <br/>
          <textarea style="display:inline-block; vertical-align:middle;" name="choice_notes" class="sub_textarea" >note2</textarea>
          <input type="checkbox" name="requiredNotes" class="requiredNotes" value="0">Required?
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="ui-sortable-handle" style="">Add Choice: <input type="text" value="Choice2" class="choice-label">
        <div  class="parentbox">
          <textarea name="choice_notes" class="sub_textarea" >note3</textarea>
          <input type="checkbox" name="requiredNotes" class="requiredNotes" value="1" checked>Required?
          <br/>
          <textarea name="choice_notes" class="sub_textarea" >note4</textarea>
          <input type="checkbox" name="requiredNotes" class="requiredNotes" value="0">Required?
          <br/>
            <textarea  name="choice_notes" class="sub_textarea" >note5</textarea>
          <input type="checkbox" name="requiredNotes" class="requiredNotes" value="1" checked>Required?
          <br/>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
     <input type='submit' class='update' value='submit' />
  </div>
</form>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="form">
  <div class="choices">
    <ul> 
      <li class="ui-sortable-handle">Add Choice: <input type="text" value="Choice1" class="choice-label">
        <div  class="parentbox">
          <textarea  name="choice_notes" class="sub_textarea" >note1</textarea>
          <input type="checkbox" name="requiredNotes" class="requiredNotes" value="1"  checked>Required?
          <br/>
          <textarea name="choice_notes" class="sub_textarea" >note2</textarea>
          <input type="checkbox" name="requiredNotes" class="requiredNotes" value="0">Required?
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="ui-sortable-handle" style="">Add Choice: <input type="text" value="Choice2" class="choice-label">
        <div  class="parentbox">
          <textarea name="choice_notes" class="sub_textarea" >note3</textarea>
          <input type="checkbox" name="requiredNotes" class="requiredNotes" value="1" checked>Required?
          <br/>
          <textarea name="choice_notes" class="sub_textarea" >note4</textarea>
          <input type="checkbox" name="requiredNotes" class="requiredNotes" value="0">Required?
          <br/>
            <textarea  name="choice_notes" class="sub_textarea" >note5</textarea>
          <input type="checkbox" name="requiredNotes" class="requiredNotes" value="1" checked>Required?
          <br/>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
     <input type='submit' class='update' value='submit' />
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have <label><input type="checkbox" class="requiredNotes" value="1" checked>Required?</label>. So that I am getting undefined value after using next()

Comment: <label><input type="checkbox" class="requiredNotes" value="1" checked>Required?</label> should give you value 1 since it was checked. Do you want to get the value of the unchecked checkboxes also? See var subNotesReqChoice=$(this).next('input.requiredNotes[type=checkbox]:checked').val();

Comment: Could you please check my code in the question? I am getting undefined after using next()

Comment: yes because you still have it as ```var subNotesReqChoice=$(this).next('input.requiredNotes[type=checkbox]').val();``` instead of ```var subNotesReqChoice=$(this).next('input.requiredNotes[type=checkbox]:checked').val();```

Comment: I have updated the code, but still get the undefined value for checkbox

Comment: I did something like .next('label').find('input.requiredNotes[type=checkbox]') and it works now. Thank you for the help

Comment: Sorry @Zendie, network went off. That's fine. You could as well add name attributes to the checkboxes like i did in the edited code and it'll work also